# Display only active item with PrimeNG Steps

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using the PrimeNG Steps component and I'd like to hide disabled menu items when I'm on a mobile.

I've tried with CSS but it does not work...

```html
<p-steps [model]="steps" [readonly]="true" [activeIndex]="activeIndex" [styleClass]="'custom-steps'"
</p-steps>
```

```scss
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .custom-steps .p-disabled .p-steps-item {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but if you want to hide an element based on screen size, you can use `window.innerWidth` and trigger a boolean to hide show it [Hide element if screen is mobile size](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ebmxt8-lipm16?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fsteps-basic-demo.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fsteps-basic-demo.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fsteps-basic-demo.ts)